# Persisting events/objects with many different dependencies

Tags: database, performance, database-design, orm

I believe the following is a pretty common use case, yet even after thinking about for a couple of hours and discussing it with a friend I found no satisfactory solution.

*Basic problem:* How do you store and efficiently query objects/entities with connections to many different relations?

**The objects**
Imagine you have a system that keeps track of a group of cars, their positions and their drivers (each is an entity in your DB/system). From monitoring the activity of the cars you are generating events such as speeding violations, collisions between two cars and fuel fillups. Now each of these events is a little different, modeled as objects they might have the following attributes:

Speeding violation

- speed (integer)
- car (reference)
- driver (reference)

Collision

- car1 (reference)
- car2 (reference)
- driver1 (reference)
- driver2 (reference)
- position (reference)
- date & time
- state (fixed or new)

Fuel fillup

- car (reference)
- amount (float)
- position (reference)

Additionally they all share some attributes such as a creation date and an owning company. It is also possible that new events will be generated in the future and these should be simple to add to whatever storage system/model gets decided on.

**Query demands**
Queries are roughly ordered in by importance (most important first). The system should be able to efficiently

- query all notifications (with their attributes) for a given company or time frame
- query all notifications belonging to a certain car or driver
- query all notifications of a certain type (e.g. all fillup notifications)

**The question**
How do you store the above described objects in a database (not necessarily relational although the referenced entities are in a relational DB) such that the queries described can be performed efficiently?

The definition of efficiency here can be pretty flexible, what is important to me is that situation where e.g. all of the dependencies have to be queried individually are avoided.

**Potential solutions**
Here are some of the ideas I came up with:

- **2 tables model**: A first table `event` holds the common general information of the events such as an id, company, event_type and creation date. A second table `event_objects` then holds all the different attachments and contains the columns id, event_id, object_id and object_type.

  - *Good:*

    - Most queries can be answered efficiently
    - Very easy to scale for additional events
    - Very easy to add new attributes for an event
  - *Bad:*

    - When the objects for a specific event have to be retrieved they each have to be fetched with an individual query
    - If the DB is relational this goes against good practice/designed use (essentially use the DB as a key-value store)
- **1 table per event**: Simply create one table for each event type with a column for each attribute

  - *Good:*

    - Events of the same type can be queried very efficiently
    - Querying all events of a company/car etc. is only linear in the number of event types (as opposed to the number of related attributes times the number of fetched events for the 2 tables model)
    - Fits more nicely with the relational model
  - *Bad:*

    - Harder to query all events of a company/for a time frame (requires #types queries)
    - Harder to add a new attribute to an existing event type

**Conclusion**
Based on the listed advantages and disadvantages I am tempted to go with the 1 table per event solution, but it still doesn't seem particularly elegant to me. I am sure I am not the first one to bump into this problem and would love to hear how others have tackled similar issues.

Comment: By saying all events have an owning company do you mean that an event is owned by a company? Or the car is owned by a company?

Comment: Also, by having an event with both a car and a driver, you are implying that a car is not just driven by one person, but can be driven by multiple drivers over time. Is this correct?

Comment: @ElliotSchmelliot: Yes the event belongs to or is associated with a company. If a car is also associated with a company or not should not be relevant for the example I think. Your assumption about the cars and drivers is correct, these have a many-to-many relationship (though again I think this is not necessarily relevant for this problem).

Comment: What do you mean by "dependencies have to be queried"? That a table with a foreign key must be joined to its referenced table? What do you mean by "fetched with an individual query"? I suspect you mean, joined in a FROM clause.

Comment: @philipxy: "dependencies have to be queried" - the solution should allow dependencies to be queried with a join, I want to avoid a situation where for each dependency an individual `SELECT` statement has to be issued.  
"fetched with an individual query" - See above, I mean an explicit `SELECT` statement or any other case where an actual individual query has to be issued (anything that can be done with a join, be it in FROM or explicit, within a query does not fall under this)

Comment: This is no help. You use the same unclear phrases I asked about & continue to use terms in a vaguely suggestive but technically strange way. That suggests misconceptions. Tables are joined, not dependencies. A query can have many selects with many joins. Given  functions on column types, any table can be returned by a single query. I can't make sense of your parenthetical distinction. Or your use of "allowed join" since any tables can be joined with a well defined meaning and [constraints are irrelevant to query meanings given base table meanings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24909854/3404097).