# Foreign key in join operations

Tags: join, foreign-keys, relational-algebra

Can anyone tell me the answer of following question in brief?
What role does the concept of foreign key play when specifying the join operations?

Comment: None. And all joins are meaningful. [Whether a particular join on a particular column set involves a foreign key is just not germane to understanding the meaning of a query.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24909854/3404097) But what role do you think it plays? And what do you mean by "the most common types of meaningful join operations"? Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time we use primary key of one table as foreign key in another table so if we use foreign key in join then it will optimize your queries.