# Joins over non-key attributes

Tags: sql, database, join

What's the meaning of joins over non-key attributes?
Is there any example?

I only know the case that Joins over the foreign key of one table with the primary key of the other table.

This is the case that joins over key attributes, isn't it?

So what's the case that joins over non-key attributes?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)
The example here is like I mentioned above.

Comment: You might want to explain why you think that "joins over non-key attributes" are in any way special. Where did you get that phrase from? What else does that source say about those joins?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23842061/3404097).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only know the case that Joins over the foreign key of one table with the primary key of the other table.

Right, that is the most common and the most heavily optimized one. However, it is not the only one: you can use a join to "connect" to rows in another table (or even in the same table) based on an arbitrary condition.

Here is a simple example of non-equijoin:

```
insert into shirt_size (size_from, size_to, size_code) values (18, 19, 'Small');
insert into shirt_size (size_from, size_to, size_code) values (20, 21, 'Medium');
insert into shirt_size (size_from, size_to, size_code) values (22, 23, 'Large');
insert into shirt_size (size_from, size_to, size_code) values (24, 25, 'XL');

SELECT g.name, s.size_code
FROM guest g
LEFT OUTER JOIN shirt_size s ON g.size >= s.size_from AND g.size <= s.size_to
```

You could use `BETWEEN` operator for the condition as well:

```
SELECT g.name, s.size_code
FROM guest g
LEFT OUTER JOIN shirt_size s ON g.size BETWEEN s.size_from AND s.size_to
```

In both cases joining happens on non-key attributes on both sides of the join condition.