# Is this normalization correct? (two many-to-manys connected by a many-to-one)

Tags: sql, database, database-design, sqlalchemy, database-normalization

I have a schema for a scorekeeping database with `Game`, `Team`, `Player` tables.

One team has many players, each player has only one team. Each team plays many games, each game has many teams. In each game, players score a certain number points individually and as a team - this maps to a `player_score` and a `team_score`. A team's total score for a game is the sum of all of its players `player_score` for that game and the team's `team_score` for that game.

This is my plan -

`GameTeam` table includes the team's `team_score` for that game, and has foreign keys of `Game.id` and `Team.id`. Many to many.

`GamePlayer` table includes the player's `player_score` for that game, and has foreign keys of `Game.id` and `Player.id`. Many to many.

So the problem is that `GameTeam` and `GamePlayer` aren't linked and it seems like they should be - since a player always belongs to one team. My solution was to add a one-to-many relationship between `GameTeam` and `GamePlayer`, then if I have a game id and a team id I can search for a `GameTeam` where those match, iterate over all the `gameTeam.gamePlayers` adding each `player_score`, add on the `team_score` at the end, and calculate `total_score`.

Does this make sense? Am I completely off? Any help appreciated, thanks. If it matters, I'm using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: For me it's fine. Any problems with the structure? I would also suggest to add an image of your DB relations to the question to let us easier understand current structure. Or it's even better to add sql fiddle.

Comment: Well it seems awkward that Game has attribute of game_teams AND game_players, when game_players belongs to game_team right? Does that matter? The alternative would be just a many to many mapping from MatchTeam and Player, which would be 3 foreign keys (a joint of match id and team id from MatchTeam, and player id)

Comment: Do you really need a relationship between `GameTeam` and `GamePlayer`? It seems to me that this relationship can be inferred from the fact that they share the same `Game` (having same `Game.id`), and players belong to just one `Team`. Or am I missing something?  
However if the player switches team, my assumption would not be something to count on, and it might effectively invalidate previous games.

Comment: They can't switch teams.
I just thought there should be a relationship because they do in real life.
So to get a team's total score, say, I would do (pseudocode) for each gameTeam in round.gameTeams { sum = gameTeam.team_score; for each gamePlayer in round.gamePlayers { if (gamePlayer.player.team.id == gameTeam.team.id) { sum += gamePlayer.player_score }}}
Does this make sense? The other way seems cleaner though, if I don't have to cross check team_ids and I can assume some set of  GamePlayers belong to a GameTeam.

Comment: This is not a "normalization", it is a(n incomplete) "design".

Answer (score 1):

The problem to your design is that you have used [surrogate identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) as the primary key for the tables, a well defined primary key will solve the problem:

```
Team   -> pk:team_id
Player -> pk:player_id
TeamPlayer -> pk:{team_id + player_id}

Game   -> pk:game_id
GameTeam -> pk:{game_id + team_id}
GamePlayer -> pk:{game_id + GameTeam_pk + TeamPlayer_pk} 
              = {game_id + {game_id + team_id} + {team_id + player_id} }
```

Having check constraints on `GamePlayer` will help the problem:

```
GamePlayer 
{
 Check game_id (FK of Game) = game_id (FK of GameTeam );
 Check team_id (FK of GameTeam) = team_id (FK of TeamPlayer);
}
```

So
 player_score will be property of `GamePlayer`.
team_score will (may) be SUM of `GamePlayer.player_score` with specific team_id.

Comment: Why is there a TeamPlayer table if Team to Player is a one to many relationship?

Comment: Does it make sense to do a many-to-many with GameTeam and Player? By well-defined primary key do you mean composite key?

Comment: Yes. I mean composite keys. If Player definition is separated from Team defecation, so you will need an association table between them. This will give you the facility that players can be assigned to deferment teams during time.

Comment: Existence of TeamPlayer table is dependent to you business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the apparently basic application relationships you are interested in. Eg:

```
Team "[team_id] identifies a team"
Player "[player_id] identifies a player"
GameTeam "[game_id] identifies a game involving team [team_id]"
TeamPlayer "player [player_id] plays for team [team_id]"
GamePlayer "in game [game_id] player [player_id] scored [player_score]"
```

Then make a table for each such relationship. A table holds the rows whose values participate in its relationship, ie that are so related. Ie it holds the rows that satify the parameterized statement (predicate) of a relationship, ie that make its parameterized statement into a true statement (proposition).

Now tables calculated by table operators satisfy relationships built by corresponding logical operaters. An INNER JOIN holds rows that satisfy the AND of its operands' relationships. For a UNION, the OR. WHERE and ON both AND in conditions. SELECTing out column C from a table with predicate "...[C]..." gives the relationship "THERE EXISTS a value for C such that ...[C]...".

"Linking" is irrelevant. A "link" is a foreign key. A FK is irrelevant to querying other than telling you that if you INNER JOIN then you only get one row from the target table per row of the source table. If there's no "link" you can still INNER JOIN for the relationship that is the AND of the operands' relationships, you just might get more than one row from the target table matching per row of the source table. (The FK tells you that IF THERE EXIST values for *source columns* such that *source relationship* THEN THERE EXIST values for *target columns* such that *target relationship*.) (Which is not a "relationship" but a fact.) Similary, regarding shared columns and INNER JOIN, SQL always conceptually initially produces a cross product for INNER JOIN of which some rows meet the given conditions. Links between columns and common columns are irrelevant. Just identify what relationship is represented by a base table or query table.

("A *p*:*q* relationship" is some *particular* relationship that *happens* to be *p*:*q*. You can't talk about its cardinality until you identify what "it" is.)

Then you have to determine base relationships/tables that are sufficient for expressing everything relevant about your application, ie suffient for expressing every relevant query relationship/table. The particular choices are what design is all about. (This will involve among other things normalization, which is about replacing relationships/tables of the form "... AND ..." by two or more of the ANDed relationships/tables. Although there isn't any normalization in your question or this answer.)