# Database + Class design guidance - Is this more complicated than it needs to be?

Tags: mysql, oop, database-design, orm, relational-database

*Novice relational database design question here. This is a "I feel like I'm doing wrong. What is it?" question. What it boils down to is, how can I avoid unnecessary complexity when designing a relational database. I also realise that this is as much a question about class structure design, seeing as I'm using an ORM and I'm really thinking of these tables as objects.*

#### Background

Lets say I want to record the results of a number of competitive games between an unspecified number of "players". These players all belong to a "leaderboard", so, the leaderboard has multiple players and records multiple results. The "score" for each of the players is recorded at the end of each game and belongs to a single "result" instance (see image). A score is also parented by the player to which it belongs.

> ### edit: An example
>
> Each row in the `leaderboard` table represents a collection of players who together form a league. For example, all of
>   the players who belong to a tennis league will have the same
>   `leaderboard_id` in the `player` table.
>
> A row in the `results` table
>   represents a match that has taken place between players that belong to
>   a particular league. So the `leaderboard_id` associated with our
>   players is recorded in each `result` in this league. The results table
>   doesn't hold the score of each player, rather, I've attempted to
>   normalise (appologies for potentially inappropriate use of that term)
>   these into a `score` table.
>
> Bringing this all together. We have a
>   league in the `Leaderboard` table, in which a game has taken places
>   between two `players`. These `players` belong to the league in
>   question. The two players have just played a match and their scores
>   are recorded as rows in the `score` table. These rows are collected
>   together under a single `results_id`, refereing to a row in the
>   `results` table.

[image]

#### Question

**Q1**. Does this make sense? Is there anything glaringly obvious that is wrong with this design?

As is, I can easily query the scores a particular player has accumulated over time, look up the players that played in a particular result, etc. However, there are some actions that really feel like they should be simple, but, to me, feel overly complicated.

For instance, if I want to return the most recent results for a particular player (ie not the player's *scores*, rather the *results* that contain a score that belongs to our player).

So, hand-wavey **Q2**. Maybe this is just lack of experience with SQL, but, I shouldn't have to do a `JOIN` to look up this, should I? But then, what's the alternative? Should I create a one-to-many composition between player and results, so that I can simply look up a player results?

With the current design to find the most recent result for a player I would need to do something like this (python sqlalchemy)

```
Score.query.join(Result, Player)\
           .filter(Player.id ==player_id)\
           .order_by(Result.timestamp.desc()).first()
```

Is this bad?

Comment: Please tell us what application relationship each table/model represents. Ie when a row/record is in each table/model, what does it state about the application situation? (Nb your diagram excises many columns/fields and their constraints/links. So it's hard to even guess.) A query returns rows/records that make statements too. The tuple-parameterized statements are built from ANDs, ORs, AND NOTs, etc of the base tuple-parameterized statements. That is calculated by JOIN/WHERE/ON, UNION, EXCEPT, etc respectively. So yes, you need SQL SELECTs to get info derived from base info.

Comment: Eg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27164733/3404097) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24749002/3404097).

Comment: @philipxy thanks for your reply. I've added in an example to the question. Hopefully this will make what each table represents clearer. I've started to look at your links. It looks as though  my `score` table is a akin to the the `GamePlayer` table in your first link. Shall report back when I've sat down to properly understand the other question and answers.