# join a to c where table a and table c has only table b as relation

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have 3 tables; `A`,`B`,`C`

`A` is in relation with `B` and `B` is in relation with `C`

I want to use select query on `A` and take a column of `C` in the query

Using inner join, I can only reach `B` but I want to reach `C` which has no direct relation with `A`

Comment: Could that be any more abstract? If you use real table names and show example data and expected output the question would be clearer.

Comment: [FKs ("relationships") are not needed to query.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23842061/3404097) Tables represent relation(ship)s/associations. What a row in a table says in terms of its columns is necessary & sufficient to query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you need to use 2 `inner joins` to get data from `tablec` like following.

```
select a.*,c.coltoselect
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on a.abcommoncolumn=b.abcommoncolumn
inner join tablec c on b.bccommoncolumn=c.bccommoncolumn
```